# Parsing String into Map using regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex, text-parsing

I'm trying to parse input such as this:

```
VAR1: 7, VAR2: [1,2,3], VAR3: value1=1,value2=2, TIMEZONE: GMT+5, TIME: 17:15:00
```

into a Map:

```
{VAR1=7, VAR2=[1,2,3], VAR3=value1=1,value2=2, TIMEZONE=GMT, TIME=17:15:00}
```

So variables are separated by commas(,) and their values come after colon(:). They're not always in caps, I wrote them like this to make it more obvious which are names of variables and which are values. Also, whitespace can appear anywhere anywhere around names or in values.
Problem is that commas can appear in values like in VAR2 or VAR3 and colons can appear in variables like TIME.

I tried splitting string like this to get values out:

```
final String regex = ",?\\s*(\\w+)\\s*:\\s*";
final String[] values = inputString.split(regex);
```

and it works as long as inputString doesn't contain any time variables with colons in its value. Otherwise it returns this as values:

```
[, 7, [1,2,3], value1=1,value2=2, GMT+5, , , 00]
```

instead of:

```
[7, [1,2,3], value1=1,value2=2, GMT+5, 17:15:00]
```

I suspect that it matches the last colon in TIME rather than the first one located after variable's name separating it from its value.
I tried using reluctant quantifier for colon ",?\s*(\w+)\s*:*?\s*" but this returned:

```
[, :, , : [, , , ], :, =, , =, , :, +, , :, :, :]
```

Which is nonsense.
I would appreciate any ideas to improve regex.

Comment: All your patterns except the first one starts with `, `, so why not `(^|,\\s+)` instead of `,?\\s*`?

Comment: Because commas can appear even inside values and would split them. The idea of my regex was to split by comma-variable name-colon pattern  so that doesn't happen.
Also white can nut doesn't have to appear. Input can be both:
    
    VAR1:7,VAR2:[1,2,3],VAR3:value1=1,value2=2,TIMEZONE:GMT+5, TIME:17:15:00

or:

    VAR1    :    7,    VAR2  :   [1,2,   3], VAR3: value1  =1,value2=2     , TIMEZONE: GMT +5,      TIME:      17:15:00

Comment: Note: you can't get rid of the first empty match using split alone. I'd probably suggest Pattern / Matcher.

Comment: True about the first empty match but I solved that by using values from index 1 instead from the begging of the field at index zero. I use Matcher to find groups (\\w+) for variable names.

Comment: By the way, just to clarify colons and commas  never appear together in values. So it can't be variable A with value B,C:D. That should mean variables A and C with values B and D respectively

Comment: Is the person who designed this format still around? Ask him or her how it should be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a variable name cannot start with a digit the colons in the date/time are not a problem. I have more issues with the commas in the values.

Here's how I solved the problem:

```
    String input = "VAR1: 7, VAR2: [1,2,3], VAR3: value1=1,value2=2, TIMEZONE: GMT+5, TIME: 17:15:00";
    Pattern re = Pattern.compile(
            "^\\s*(\\p{Alpha}\\p{Alnum}*)\\s*:\\s*(\\S*)(?:,\\s*(\\p{Alpha}\\p{Alnum}*\\s*:.*))?$");
    Matcher matcher = re.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.matches()) {
        String name = matcher.group(1);
        String value = matcher.group(2);
        String tail = matcher.group(3);
        System.out.println(name + ": " + value);
        if (tail == null) {
            break;
        }
        matcher = re.matcher(tail);
    }
```

Result:

```
VAR1: 7
VAR2: [1,2,3]
VAR3: value1=1,value2=2
TIMEZONE: GMT+5
TIME: 17:15:00
```

UPDATE:

It also works with:

```
    Pattern re = Pattern.compile(
            "^\\s*(\\w+)\\s*:\\s*(\\S*)(?:,\\s*(\\w+\\s*:.*))?\\s*$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution ([online test](https://regex101.com/r/ObCbtm/1/)):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(.+?):\\s?(.+?)(?:,\\W|$)";
final String string = "VAR1: 7, VAR2: [1,2,3], VAR3: value1 =1,value2=2, TIMEZONE: GMT+5, TIME: 17:15:00";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Just collect the results in a map to obtain what you asked for

Regex explanation:

- `(.+?)`: Captures your keys (example: `VAR1`)
- `:`: Captures the `:` symbol literally
- `\s?`: Captures an optional space
- `(.+?)`: Captures your values (example: `7`)
- `(?:,\\W|$)`: Captures a comma followed by a space (these two symbols together are our actual separator) OR the end of the string